# RESTful Javascript frameworks and RESTful PHP frameworks

Tags: rest, slim, canjs

This is my first time trying to get into RESTful frameworks for Javascript and PHP. Specifically, they are the micro-frameworks `CanJS` for Javascript and `Slim` for PHP.

They each seem to map the 4 HTTP "verbs" (Get, Post, Put, Delete) to database CRUD operations.

So, in what cases would one use one over the other? In what cases would one use both in tandem?

Explain like I'm five? (This is probably going to be edited out, but sorry, I couldn't resist.)

Comment: Use the one for the language you know best.  REST is HTTP, so you can use any front end technology that can make an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your code says to CanJS, "Please **findOne** of this Foo object; the ID is 1"

CanJS models say to Slim services, "Hello, can I **GET** this object that you have at /foos/1 ?"

Slim says "Sure, here's some text that represents it { BLAH BLAH BLAH }"

CanJS and Slim agreed beforehand on what an object looks like, so when CanJS sees the text, it knows how to make an object out of it by **parsing**

CanJS takes the text, parses it, makes something that looks like a Foo (Foo is a special type of **can.Model** that you made by subclassing) out of it, and sends it back to your code using a **success** callback or a **resolved** promise.

When you use a framework on the client side that wraps around REST, you always need a matching service on the server side that provides REST endpoints (something to handle GET/POST/PUT/DELETE requests).  So it's not a matter of choosing between CanJS and Slim, but a matter of choosing Slim versus something else to work together with (provide the data to) CanJS.

Comment: Thanks. Some clarifications please: (1) Why would one need PHP at the back end at all? After all AJAX can work directly with the database, no? (2) So, would one necessarily need a ReST wrapper server framework at the server end? Would plain PHP work instead?

Comment: (1) No.  AJAX doesn't work directly with databases *except for* some special cases like MongoDB in development versions (you'd never want to deploy that in production).

Comment: (2) if you don't need to do the full CRUD life cycle on data objects (e.g. you're just reading data from a database and not updating it), you may not need REST at all.  It has to do with the needs of your app.  REST makes working with objects consistent, and you should use REST if you need to work with objects consistently.  Using a browser framework like CanJS ends up taking some of what PHP usually does (rendering data into pages) away from the server, in order to make pages more dynamic (sometimes using just a single page for the whole app), and needs raw data via REST to do that.

Comment: Wonderful explanations. Thanks for taking the time.